# write the same code from aspx page to behind code in the cs page

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

is there a way to write this code from an aspx page
to a behind code of the aspx page (cs), in asp.net.

```
<a rel="lightbox" id="userImageLightBox" runat="server" title="profile image">
    <img id="userImage"  runat="server"  width="150"  height="146"  alt="" src=""/>
</a>
```

for example if i have the code in apsx:

```
<asp:Label ID="pageProfileHeadName" runat="server" Visible="true"/>
```

in the behind code i can do:

```
    Label label = new Label();
    label.ID = "pageProfileHeadName";
    label.Visible = true;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already set the `runat="server"` attribute, you can access the HTML controls in your code-behind through its `id`:

```
// *.aspx:
<a id="userImageLightBox" runat="server" ...>
    <img id="userImage" runat="server" ... />
</a> 

// code-behind:
userImageLightBox.Title = "New Title";
userImage.Src = "~/images/profile.png";

// To get or set an attribute like `rel`:
userImageLightBox.Attributes["rel"] = "test";
```

---

**Update:** If you want to create the HTML from the code-behind, you can do as JonH wrote:

```
HyperLink a = new HyperLink();
  a.ID = "userImageLightBox";
  a.Attributes["rel"] = "lightbox";

  Image img = new Image();
  img.ID = "userImage";
  img.ImageUrl = "img.png";
  img.Width = 150;
  img.Height = 146;

  a.Controls.Add(img);
```

Oh, and please increase your accept rate.

Comment: Hi Dennis thanks for the answer but this is not what I am looking for I whant to write the code i published in the code behind not in the sapx code

Comment: Okay, then I probably misunderstood the question. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, If I can bother you with another question how can I include in the Hyperlink  the image url, and the image high ? thanks agen

Comment: Thanks for fast answers
You've been very Helpful

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - yes - a hyperlink control renders as `<a>` so you could do this:

```
Hyperlink a = new Hyperlink();
a.ID = "userImageLightBox";
```

See the MSDN regarding this server control:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0b15efk(v=vs.71).aspx

Anytime a control is `runat=server` this means you will be able to access it from the aspx code behind page (.cs, .vb, etc). So if you ever want to change a specific property, such as the `NavigateURL` property you could do so.

```
a.NavigateURL = "someURL";
```

Comment: But how can I write the rel="lightbox"  from the code behind there is no a.rel = "" thanks